# Get the output of a Azure pipeline tab

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-query-result-tabs?view=azure-devops describes how to add tabs to the output of an azure build pipeline.

[image]

I am able to get all of the output of a build pipeline run except the tabs using the Azure Devops REST API. How can I get the tab output?

I have seen the tabs referred to as 'Views' but I can't find any way to see the 'Views' either.

What am I missing? Thanks